# sorting dates and time (in text form) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar, sorting, date-time

My date and time entries in my excel file are written in the form of: Feb 18 at 3:50pm. All of this is in one cell. I was wondering if there is a way to sort this out (arrange chronologically)

Comment: As indicated in the response below, you need to provide a little more information regarding the problem. If the cells are formatted as indicated they should sort anyway, so I assume that they are text values? If the text is in A1 and you use the formula =Datevalue(A1) it will either error (if it is text) or return a number.

Comment: You need to convert the string into a "real" dateTime; and then sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click one cell > Format cells, check whether you set Custom format like `mmm dd \at h:mm AM/PM` for cells.

If yes, you may set other formats for cells to check this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date/time value from the text in the format shown using this formula (assuming the value is in A1):

=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2)&"/"&MONTH(DATEVALUE(1&LEFT(A1,3)))) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(":",A1)-3)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(":",A1)-3)-2) & " " & RIGHT(A1,2))

then format the cell containing the formula as suggested by Emily in her answer using custom formats to return it to the original look:
mmm dd \at h:mm AM/PM

then sort the column and it should sort from earliest to latest.

NB: this assumes the dates are this year.

In the picture below, column B contains the formula above, columns C and D simpy have =B1 but are formatted differently.

[image]

Regards
Justin